# Umbraco CMS 5.0 CTP 1 installation skip some steps and does not populate DB

Tags: umbraco

*I tried posting this to the ServerFault forum, but maybe StackOverflow is the right place.*

I wish to try Umbraco CMS 5.0 CTP 1 since it has a good reputation.

Since im into ASP MVC 3, I thought I would try to install the preview of V5. I know this might be buggy, but I did expect that I could install it properly, but that was not correct.

Please see the whole post here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/307546/umbraco-cms-5-0-ctp-1-installation-skip-some-steps-and-does-not-populate-db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTM is now out http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/81440

Comment: Yes, I did install the new version and it was working, so this is not an issue anymore. Thanx for point out that the new version is out :P